# Function returns NULL instead of a value

Tags: php

I wrote a function that I thought cannot be more basic:

In functions.php:

```
function testowa() {
$stringToReturn = "pies";
return $stringToReturn;
}
```

Then I'm trying to call it in single.php:

```
include_once ('functions.php');

testowa();
var_dump($stringToReturn);
```

And `var_dump` displays NULL.

Where could I possibly do anything wrong?

Comment: Undefined variable. Read up on variable scopes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: |...|=> http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: include_once ('functions.php');

$stringToReturn = testowa();
var_dump($stringToReturn);

Comment: `$xxx = testowa(); var_dump($xxx);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign the function's response to a variable. Try

```
$stringToReturn = testowa();
var_dump($stringToReturn);
```

Comment: Seems I might be too dumb to understand tutorials. Works like a charm, thank you kind sir. I will mark your answer as correct as soon as the system allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

@Michał Skrzypek update your function.php file like below:

```
<?php
    function testowa() {
        global  $stringToReturn;
        $stringToReturn = "pies";
        return $stringToReturn;
    }
```

Comment: `global` is a bad approach, stay away from using that.

Answer (score 0):

Some ways to rome.

Return Value Version:

```
function testowa() {
  return = "pies";
}
print testowa();
```

Reference Version

```
function testowa(&$refer) {
  $refer = "pies";
}
$refer = '';
testowa($refer);
print $refer;
```

Global Version

```
function testowa() {
  global $global;
  $global = "pies";
}
$global='';
testowa();
print $global;
```

But take the `Return Value Version` and avoid `Global Version`